# Passing a variable to template function in org-capture-templates

Tags: org-mode, elisp

I'm using org-capture to insert expenses into a Ledger file with this template, along with auto-completion for the various expense categories:

```
(setq ledger-expense-completions
    (list
     "" ;; needed for first | for mapconcat
     "Expenses:Food" "Expenses:Food:Restaurants" "Expenses:Food:Groceries"
     ))

(setq capture-expense-template
    "%%(org-read-date) * %%^{Description}
  %%^{Expense%s}  %%^{Amount}
  Account:Cash")

(defun return-capture-expense-template () 
    (let ((compstring
        (mapconcat 'identity ledger-expense-completions  "|" )))
            (format capture-expense-template compstring)))

(setq org-capture-templates
    (append '(("l" "Ledger entries")
              ("lc" "Cash" plain
              (file "~/Documents/journal.ledger")
              (function return-capture-expense-template)
              :empty-lines-before 1
              :empty-lines-after 1))
            org-capture-templates))
```

This works fine, however I'd like to modify `return-capture-expense-template` to make it a bit more dynamic so that I can pass in the account, e.g., `"Account:Bank"` or `"Account:Cash"`, to support variations of this template without creating a separate `capture-expense-template` for each variation.

So here's how I modified things:

```
(setq ledger-expense-completions
    (list
     "" ;; needed for first | for mapconcat
     "Expenses:Food" "Expenses:Food:Restaurants" "Expenses:Food:Groceries"
     ))

(setq capture-expense-template
    "%%(org-read-date) * %%^{Description}
  %%^{Expense%s}  %%^{Amount}
  %s")


(defun return-capture-expense-template (account) 
    (let ((compstring
        (mapconcat 'identity ledger-expense-completions  "|" )))
            (format capture-expense-template compstring account)))

(setq org-capture-templates nil)
(setq org-capture-templates
    (append '(("l" "Ledger entries")
              ("lc" "Cash" plain
              (file "~/Documents/journal.ledger")
              (function return-capture-expense-template "Account:Bank")
              :empty-lines-before 1
              :empty-lines-after 1))
            org-capture-templates))
```

When I try evaluating `(return-capture-expense-template "Account:Bank")` on a separate line, that gives me the template output that I would expect (with `"Account:Bank"` dynamically inserted into the capture template), however when I run org-capture, I get `Wrong number of arguments` because the `"Account:Bank"` is not getting passed to `return-capture-expense-template` on this line: `(function return-capture-expense-template "Account:Bank")`.

I reviewed [the docs for Anonymous Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html#index-function) and tried writing that line in various ways, but nothing I do seems to be working.

Is it not possible to pass a variable to a function when using the special form `function`?

Comment: The function needs to take zero arguments. Just move `"Account:Bank"` into the function.

Comment: I think I am trying the same thing as you do at the moment, but even with sachas answer I couldn't make it work (I am just learning to read emacs-lisp). Could you share your working solution, please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify your own properties in the property list for the template, and then you can access those properties with `plist-get` and `org-capture-plist`. Here's a brief example:

```
(defun my/expense-template ()
  (format "Hello world %s" (plist-get org-capture-plist :account)))
(setq org-capture-templates '(("x" "Test entry 1" plain
                               (file "~/tmp/test.txt")
                               (function my/expense-template)
                               :account "Account:Bank")
                              ("y" "Test entry 2" plain
                               (file "~/tmp/test.txt")
                               (function my/expense-template)
                               :account "Account:AnotherBank")))
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much, Sacha! :-) That is _exactly_ what I was looking for.

Comment: Hah, this problem was driving me nuts. Reading your emacs configuration file convinced me that good org-capture templates are an utter necessity, so it's appropriate that you happen to be the one who finally provides the answer!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Sacha's `my/expense-template` is:

```
(defun my/expense-template ()
  (format "Hello world %s" (org-capture-get :account)))
```

We spare some code by using the org-specialised `org-capture-get`.